# Nested_form inside table rows

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I'm using nested_form inside one of my Rails forms.  I saw you can generate `tr` 's instead of of `div` 's using this article https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/wiki/How-To:-Render-nested-fields-inside-a-table

Where would the javascript go though that they suggest?

```
window.nestedFormEvents.insertFields = function(content, assoc, link) {
  var $tr = $(link).closest('tr');
  return $(content).insertBefore($tr);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, **its not like "*you can generate `TR` 's instead of of `DIV`***". The link says that you can disable inserting `DIV`s. And you can add the `td`, `tr` explicitly. Like in the link they added `td` and `tr` in their form.

And sometimes you create forms by javascript and by default those fields are also wrapped with `DIV`. But you can change the behavior by using that javascript snippet. It will override the corresponding method with this new one.

Let me know if I could clear up your confusions.

Comment: Ok, so using nested_form, where would I place the javascript they say to use?  This is the given nested_form.js http://pastie.org/5053124

Comment: Well u can simply add this in the `application.js`. Actually you just need to make sure that these lines of code are loaded with your web page. Though i didnt use this way personally, but it should be like that. Let me know if doesnt work. I will try this out myself :)

Comment: Just to add. Refer https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form#specifying-a-target-for-nested-fields